# Running 2 Thunderbolt 5k LG monitors on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, graphics, lg-monitor

I have 2 5k LG monitors I am trying to use with windows 10.

MY computer has a fully compatible thunderbolt 3 card, and both displayport inputs are connected to my graphics card.

When i have one monitor plugged in, I can run it at the full 5K resolution. I can also run 2 other screens via the HDMI outputs from the graphics card (so one display at 5K, 2 display at 1080).

When I plug the second monitor in, windows detects it, but doesn't see it as a display device, unless I unplug the other monitor...

I am aware you can only run ONE screen at 5k, but even when i turn the screen down to 4k resolution, it still doesn't see the other monitor.

The problem seems to be that the thunderbolt card is only assigning the displayport to one of the thunderbolt ports? I'm not sure,

The Thunderbolt card is a Asus ThunderboltEX 3-TR.

Is there any way to get both screens working in windows?

Comment: It's dependant on your GPU capabilities, not the thunderbolt.

Comment: @tesujin I just said my GPU is displaying on 3 different displays...the GPU can support 2 screens at 4k...it is a GEFORCE RTX TI

Comment: the problem is the thunderbolt card is sending the 2 displayport inputs only to one thunderbolt port...I need to it send one stream to each